# How to detect is it window.location.reload or location.href called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have methods inside which `window.location.reload` or `location.href` has been invoked. I need to detect if it's `window.location.reload` or `location.href` that has been invoked.

If it is `window.location.reload` I will not do any processing. Otherwise I will ask the user for confirmation.

Comment: All you can do is hook to `onbeforeunload`, but there's no way to differentiate *how* this event was called.

Comment: And you can't return a custom message with `onbeforeunload` anymore because it's not supported (At least not on Google Chrome),

Answer (score 1):

> I have methods

If you control the methods, then you should add the `do_any_processing()` call there, before you unload the page. That would be the cleanest path.

Less tidy would be to set a global state flag (to some value like 'reload' or 'redir') before the unload event, and then check for that flag in your `onunload` hook.

Comment: But how can i identity that this is the window.location.reload()?

Comment: You said that you "controll the methods inside which it is invoked". So you know what you do, `location.reload()` or `location.href`. When you update `href` then simply call your `do_any_processing()` function right before it.